# JS Function executing too fast

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm doing a JSON call like this:

```
var desc = getItemDescriptions(xxx);

function getItemDescriptions(xxx) {
var url = "xxx;
var info = {};

request({
url: url,
json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        info ["..."] = body.result[xxx].yyy;
        info ["..."] = body.result[xxx].yyy;
        info ["..."] = body.result[xxx].yyy;
        info ["..."] = body.result[xxx].yyy;
        info ["..."] = body.result[xxx].yyy;
    }
})
return info;
}
```

My Problem is, the JSON request need some time to get response back... and my function doesn't wait for this response. The Function returns the empty array without waiting.

How can i wait for response and then return the filled array?

thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: what framework are you using? where is the "request" function defined?

Comment: @navotgil https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: Add an event-trigger when the request is done, perhaps? The listen for that and executen on triggered.

Comment: from npm docs:
    request.get('http://google.com/img.png').on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) // 200 
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']) // 'image/png' 
  })

Answer (score 0):

Its not like executing fast, it is the way javascript runs statement after statement. To get the data you need to do that in success callback function, the data would be available only when the server response comes back as its asynchronous call by the time response comes your javascript executes next statements.

Answer (score 0):

Juhana already linked to you the best place to get a good solution. [How to return the response from an async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

A quick and dirty hack would be (if request is a jQuery-like Ajax-function) to make the request synchronus.

This might be done by adding `async: false` to the first parameter passed to request:

`request({ url: url,json: true, async: false}, function ....`

That way `return info` will be executed AFTER your request has finished.

HTH
Georg

Comment: The other way is, when using JQuery, adding a `success` callback

Comment: If you think this has been correctly flagged as a duplicate, why do you answer anyway?

Comment: @IngoBürk I answered because I thought i can clarify this to the original poster, and provide him with a quick and dirty hack.